# Maxlength for GWT TextArea

Tags: gwt

I am unable to set the maximum length for a GWT TextArea. Could someone help me  achieve this in GWT?

```
TextArea t1 = new TextArea();
t1.setMaxLength(300); // This method doesn't exist. How do I do this?
```

Comment: What do you mean you are unable to set the max length ? What exactly is the problem, you havent said much except you are having a problem.

Comment: Hi, I want to restrict user not enter more than 300 characters, I looked in to api, there is not method which can does for me. how i can achieve this in gwt

Answer (score 14):

Gal's answer is right with just one correction :

```
t1.getElement().setAttribute("maxlength", "100");
```

The second parameter is a string. This worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, I should remove my comment. My problem was I use GXT component.

Answer (score 7):

You can set it as such:

```
t1.getElement().setAttribute("maxlength", "100");
```

Answer (score 3):

Its cause maxLength is a html5 feature, so it would not work in older browsers. You have to doit by yourself. Just add a keyPresshandler and count the length of the text in the textarea and cut the text if its to long.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but when i copy content from word file (which has more than 300 chars) and paste on text area, even this time also it should not allow. please help me to fix this.

Comment: Have you test that it doesn't work with keyPressHandler. After all 2 keys are pressed on copy paste. Ahh but not when you use the context menu. Seems you have to use a JSNI method to implement the paste event by yourself: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html

Comment: I used all handlers, which actually works but not when i cut copy paste. is there way to do this. thanks

Comment: As I mention in the last comment you have to create a JSNI function that adds the eventListener for the paste event in pure JavaScript.

Comment: Hi, Do you have any sample JSNI code which can do this, please help me thanks11

Comment: @Delli: Please read through [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915997/textfield-change-event-only-triggers-on-blur) before deciding to rely on the paste event.

Comment: @Chris, thanks for response, which is really helped, thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

For the browsers which doesn't support HTML5, here is a workaround (an extension of gwt TextArea class with maxLength feature.)

http://www.karmicbee.com/gwt-textarea-with-max-character-limits/